# Pipeline loop with sum

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I'm working with a Zedboard and I'm trying to optimize some functions in Vivado HLS.

However, when there are functions like the following where I don't know what to do.

E.g:

```
for(i=0;i<end;i++){
    sum+=i;
}
```

I can't pipeline this because each cycle depends on the previous. Is there any workaround to make the Pipeline directive function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was and why I wasn't able to pipeline this. Vivado HLS found a way to treat `sum += i`as a constant multiplication and so the latency remained constant.

Therefore, if the latency is constant, the pipleine didn't make sense.